# SpriteKit iOS8 different physical behavior

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, ios8, skphysicsbody, skphysicsjoint

i've noticed different behaviors in Physics, for example:

I have coded a rope with many SKSpriteNode and SKPhysicsJointLimit for the chain.
At the ends i've attached two SKPhysicsJointSpring to two physics-disabled SKSpriteNode.

On iOS7 it works like a charm, in iOS8 there are some "distorsion" on the rope.
These are the pics, the little square is just a joint for touch and the big rectangle is just a trigger.

In iOS8 you can see a "U" distorsion around the candy, but not in iOS7. Why?

iOS7 Launcher http://i.imgur.com/yRt6UfB

iOS8 Launcher http://i.imgur.com/WE3Esuu

Comment: Is the candy being rotated anywhere?

Comment: allow rotation can be one problem second problem may be that physics unit changes in ios8 check out the mass of every dynamic body in different iOS version for e.g. ios8/ios7

Comment: Thank you for replies. The candy is detached from the launcher, the problem can be the mass of every node and physics unit. I'll try to debug it.

Comment: Nothing, mass and other things seems be ok. Allow rotations was disabled in iOS7 and is disabled in iOS8. Why is too different between 7 and 8? I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

The right PhysicsJoint for a rope is SKPhysicsJointPin and not SKPhysicsJointLimit.
This solution works well in iOS7 and iOS8.

Answer (score 0):

I also had some serious troubles with ios8 physics behabiour... But for th e rope problem mybe you can checkout my code from this answer. It runs the same on ios7 and ios8
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20855093/3148874